# Knockout JS and large models

Tags: javascript, performance, knockout.js

I am trying to figure out the best ways of using KnockoutJS and I need your advice.

My view model contains a set of "documents" each of them has a set of "values".
Each "document" is rendered as a separate table using the following template:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: Documents">
        <table data-bind="foreach: Values">
            <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
                 <td data-bind="attr: {colspan: Colspan}">
                    <label data-bind="text: Label"></label>
                    <br />
                    <span data-bind="html: Value"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Everything works fine except when view models are big.

For example, if the size of a view model is about 1 megabyte (and contains 80 documents with 60 values each) then the rendering takes more than two minutes on my machine.

I am wondering if there is a way to significantly improve performance... Or will it be faster to give up on Knockout and just build html on a server side and just push it to the browser...

Rendering "just" 300kb view model takes close to 30 seconds.

The "documents" are defined by users, so there are even >2 megabytes scenarios (I don't know why do they do it).

Does anyone have an experience with large view models in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current requirement of being unable to lazy-load (load on demand) data, you are pretty limited.

**SERVER SIDE HTML**

Generating the HTML server-side will be the fastest method. But even so if the model is huge there's going to be a delay. Consider downloading a 5MB HTML file, it's going to take your browser some time to parse and render something so large.

**STILL USE KNOCKOUT JS**

If you want to still use your Knockout JS framework then my best suggestion is put each Document in an IFRAME. This isn't really recommended and would put extra load on your server, but if implemented correctly would speedup your user experience.

```
www.mysite.com/view/1

<div>
    <iframe src="www.mysite.com/view/1/document/1"></iframe></div>
<div>
    <iframe src="www.mysite.com/view/1/document/2"></iframe></div>
...

www.mysite.com/view/1/document/1

<!-- Just the single Document template -->
   <table data-bind="foreach: Values">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
             <td data-bind="attr: {colspan: Colspan}">
                <label data-bind="text: Label"></label>
                <br />
                <span data-bind="html: Value"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The client browser will initially get all the HTML containing all of the IFRAMEs it will dispatch requests for each asynchronously. Each single Document request will be rendered using Knockout JS in its own frame asynchronously.

To improve the user interaction you could even set up load events on the IFRAMEs. The load event could either re-size the IFRAME so there's no scroll bar, or extract the HTML from the IFRAME and replace the IFRAME element with the extracted HTML.

Comment: Thanks. So playing with how my view model is structured will not really help according to your answer? I mean, if I do two-phase bindings: bind an empty table first and then bind that table in order to populate it with data, etc?

Comment: Also from your experience, does it make sense to try other MVVM frameworks or template engines (like backbone, jQuery.tmpl, etc) or the performance is doing to be pretty much the same? In other words, is it a general JavaScript/Browser/Dom problem or is it just Knockout that being slow? Of course I will try at least one other framework myself, but trying all of them takes a lot of time so that's why I am asking for an advice from experienced guys :)

Comment: @Alexey Raga - Any time you do binding on the client side your performance will be limited by the browser. What if someone is using IE8 (slow JavaScript engine) and the model is huge, it'll take them minutes to render it. You didn't really give any bounds for what you'd consider "significantly improve performance" if jQuery.tmpl is 50% faster would that be enough for you?...

Answer (score 2):

The native template engine in KO is not particularly fast. I would try the jQuery.tmpl engine ([described here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)) first. If that isn't fast enough, you should consider trying to reduce the amount of content being rendered - say, only rendering a header for each document initially and then rendering the details when it is selected or expanded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am discussing this with business, but as for now they want everything to be rendered at once...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your application works but if you don't need to show all that content at once, you can populate your model in pieces. Like in one of my applications I have view model which has big list of items but it only contains things which are visible in the table. View also has selected item entry which has more information and I populate it when some entry is selected from the list.

In general I have seen few times that people are putting all kinds of stuff the the view model even it's not ever rendered in the UI. It has some benefits if you get your stuff directly from the server, but on the other hand it may bloat the view model.